# DNN DDR module - Get current page name and description

Tags: c#, razor, dotnetnuke

I'm using this code to create a template for DDR menu using CurrentChildren only:

```
@using DotNetNuke.Web.DDRMenu;
@using System.Dynamic; 
@inherits DotNetNuke.Web.Razor.DotNetNukeWebPage<dynamic>

@{ var root = Model.Source.root; }

<link rel="Stylesheet" href="whatever/styles.css" />

@helper RenderNodes(IList<MenuNode> nodes) {
    <h1>@Dnn.Tab.TabName</h1>
    if (nodes.Count > 0) {
        <div class="sc-element">
            <div class="row co-tiles-wrapper"> 
                @foreach (var node in nodes)
                {
                    if (node.Enabled) {             
                        //whatever @node.Text
                    } else {
                        //whatever @node.Text
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}

@RenderNodes(root.Children)
```

However I now need to add the current page title at the beginning (top) of the page. It's not the children page name during the loop. It's the name of the page where the ddr module is being loaded.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your Razor template:

```
@using DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals;

<h1>@PortalSettings.Current.ActiveTab.TabName</h1>
```

In a DNN theme you can use <%=PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabName%>

This and more examples:  https://demo.40fingers.net/dnn-framework-attributes-demo-skin

Comment: This is not a DNN theme. It's a DDR c# template.

Comment: Ok, I guess you mean a razor template. I added that too

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll add this to my example Theme

Comment: This page has all the attributes needed: https://demo.40fingers.net/dnn-framework-attributes-demo-skin/Pages
It's just missing the razor implementation.

Comment: yes, I mean adding it to https://demo.40fingers.net/dnn-ddr-demo-skin